# Is there default catch all route to new actions in Play 2?

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.1

In Play 1, new actions you defined had a default route.

```
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

(This appeared by default in new projects)

What is the Play 2/2.1 equivalent?
Why doesn't it appear in the default routes file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually there is a catch-all route available. According to the [routing doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaRouting) in Play 2.0+ you can use **Dynamic parts spanning several /** so if you put it as exactly **last** route of given method it will catch every route that wasn't catch before. You can use this for further processing for an example if you have other 'routes' stored in DataBase.

```
GET   /*path   controllers.Application.seacrhRouteInDB(path: String)
```

Comment: Any idea why it's not in the default routes file?

Comment: Cause it's my... 'innovation' :D And serious - Play doesn't enforce you to use specific behaviors (fortunately) so you can use that trick _if required_ and for most cases it isn't required...

Comment: This is a really neat trick you've found :) My answer now looks ridiculous in comparison.

Comment: @MirkoAdari, no it isn't using `Global` class can be another solution

Comment: @PabloFernandez - that's easy: you can store URL's in DB and use your controller to resolve it... its basics in 99% of PHP CMSes...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the routes in Play Framework 2 don't have this feature.. However you can create a `Global` class that extends `GlobalSettings` and implement the catch all in the `onRouteRequest` method. Check [API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/java/index.html) or [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGlobal) for details.

Note this is only available since 2.1.0.

Comment: No chance to get a code sample, right? I guess you haven't implemented this yourself yet...

Comment: As 2.1.0 was just released, haven't needed it yet anywhere. Just remembered seeing this in the release notes.

Comment: I picked a delicate time to migrate from 1.2.4 :)

Comment: Be prepared for a lot more, Play Framework 2 is entirely different product. We keep our 1.2.5 projects on 1.2.5, but start new ones on 2.x.

Comment: Yeah, I know. No real plan to migrate, but we thought it's about time we tasted some Play 2 + Scala.