# Writing the uri pattern in the url

Tags: scala, url, playframework-2.6

I'am using play framework 2.6 with scala, I want to prevent accessing my web pages from url .In the usual case if i write the URI pattern  in the url it will redirct to the web page  by executing the associated action ,for example if i write in the url : http://localhost:9000/home it will redirect to the home page, but what i want is to redirect to error page rather than the home page when writing an URI (in this case: /home) in the url.

```
my routes file
GET  /home controllers.HomeController.index()
```

Comment: do you mean you want to navigate from some internal links but not directly from url?

Comment: my scenario is : when i run the app it appear the login page if success authentication go to home page else we stay at the login page, that's work fine.My problem is when I'am on the login page I can go to the home page without sign in only by adding to the url /home

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868153/authorisation-check-in-controller-scala-play try this

Answer (score 0):

You can [redirect in the controller method](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActions#Redirects-are-simple-results-too):

```
# my routes file
GET  /home controllers.HomeController.errorRedirect()

# HomeController
...
  def errorRedirect = Action {
    Redirect("/error")
  }
```

or perhaps you want to [catch all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15121242/1240268) and then redirect:

```
# my routes file
GET  /home controllers.HomeController.home()
GET  /*path controllers.HomeController.errorRedirect()
```

*See also: [supplying a custom error handler](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaErrorHandling#Supplying-a-custom-error-handler) in the play docs.*

Comment: my scenario is : when i run the app it appear the login page if success authentication go to home page else we stay at the login page, that's work fine.My problem is when I'am on the login page  I can go to the home page without sign in only by adding to the url /home